# What is this feature name in VS 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, split-screen

In Visual Studio 2019, I can see this icon to adjust the different panes:

[image: Cropped screen shot from Visual Studio]

What is this feature name in VS 2019 and VS 2017?
This handle can vertically split the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the splitter control. It's found in a lot Microsoft apps like Word or Excel. Alternatively click Split on the Window menu. See [Customize window layouts in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/customizing-window-layouts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019)

It's similar to [Splitter Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/splitter-control-windows-forms) for Windows Forms